# How to use NamedQuery in JPA

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I am trying to use NamedQuery in JPA as per example i have defined something like that:

```
@Stateless
@Local
@Slf4j
@NamedQuery(
    name="findAllCustomer",
    query="select p.owner from UserInfo p where p.customer.id= :cusId")
public class CustomerDAOBean extends GenericDAO<Integer, Person>{

public List<Person> findAllCustomers(Integer customerId) {

      return  em.createNamedQuery("findAllCustomer")
                .setParameter("cusId",customerId)
                .getResultList();
}
```

but getting exception like this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: findAllCustomer not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing it in the entity class